# Is there an optimal placement for timing/frequency words?

Tags: particle-に, sentence, time

I'm using Duolingo to supplement a 101 course I took and it doesn't really explain that well where timing/frequency words should appear in a sentence. For the sentence "I often play baseball with my older brother", Duolingo defaults to the below answer:

**よく**兄とやきゅうをします

Frequency word in bold. However, it also accepts a few others:

兄と**よく**やきゅうをします

兄とやきゅうを**よく**します

I don't know if these are correct, it's just what the app accepts as an answer. Does it matter? In English there would be many ways to write that sentence: "Often I play...", "I often play...", "I play often...". Is it something like that perhaps?

I've noticed, though, that if there's a time word with the particle に, then it will only accept an answer if it's in front, like in the sentence "I play baseball with my older brother on Saturday":

**土曜日に**兄とやきゅうをします

Why is it different here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [よく][兄と][野球を]します。

In this sentence, three segments I indicated with [] can be grammatically placed in any order, though their nuance are slightly different.

> [土曜日に][兄と][野球を]します。

This is also the case when you change よく to 土曜日に. Duolingo sometimes fails to judge your answer when there are variety of possible answers, but it's just a Duolingo-specific problem, which you don't have to warry about in actual use.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! You mentioned nuance, if you can elaborate, what do you mean? Is it a dialect difference or something else?

Comment: The choice of word order involves multiple factors. One is a focus. People often considers "when > where > subject > object" as a neutral order, so when certain part is moved afterward, it gets "focused" nuance. That is, 兄と野球を土曜日にします focuses more on 土曜日に (like "it is on Saturday that I play baseball with my older brother") than 土曜日に兄と野球をします, which considered neutral.

Comment: Another factor is ambiguity and clarity. When people write long complicated sentences (such as ones with subordinate clause) or use demonstratives, for example, people try to arrange the word order to avoid unintended interpretation or prevent readers from making too much effort.

Comment: afterward > backward

Comment: Great explanation, thank you! I've progressed further in Duolingo and now it is mixing up the ordering just as you've described. It's similar to the two sentences "Lets play baseball this Saturday" and "This Saturday, lets play baseball". Slightly different emphasis.